# Asignación de color a letras en un input

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Quiero asignar el color a cada una de las letras que se visualizan en un input es decir que si escribo pedro se le asigne un color para

```
p---verde // e---rojo// r----rosado// o--amarillo
```

```js
function miFuction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = x;
}

function muestra_color() {
  var letras = {
    a: '#EA1437',
    b: '#D8EA14',
    c: '#4AEA14',
    d: '#2BA97E',
    e: '#0E1EC2',
    f: '#460EC2',
    g: '#A90EC2',
    h: '#C20E3A',
    i: '#EA1437',
    j: '#D8EA14',
    k: '#4AEA14',
    l: '#2BA97E',
    m: '#0E1EC2',
    n: '#460EC2',
    ñ: '#084213',
    o: '#2C0842',
    p: '#66EAD8',
    q: '#F0E630',
    r: '#6A61A2',
    s: '#A28261',
    t: '#DE2D08',
    u: '#B24C5C',
    v: '#95A5A6',
    w: '#0B5345',
    x: '#34495E',
    y: '#07E816',
    z: '#07E8A0'
  };
  var letra = color.docuemt.getElementById("input").value;
  var color = document.getElementById("resultado").value;
  var colorvalue = letras[color];
  var result = `
<p style="color:${colorvalue}">${letra}</p>`
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML += result;
}
```

```html
<div class="wraper-2">
  <input placeholder="Escribe tu nombre" class="txt-resultado" id="input" value="NOMBRE" oninput="miFuction()">
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="wraper-3" id="oninput">
  <p class="txt_resultado" id="resultado"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Cuál es la pregunta o el error con el código?

Comment: No veo donde llamas las funciones, coloca el código completo para entender la lógica con la que intentas hacerlo

Comment: que sigo escribiendo y aun asi no me aparece los colores de asigancion como lo digo anteriormente

Comment: En tu código html, llamas a una función llamada `myFunction`, pero dentro de esta, en ningún momento llamas a `muestra_color()`

Comment: al llamar la otra funcion no me genera nada

Comment: de hecho porque `colorvalue = letras[color];` retorna undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay varias cosas a corregir en tu código:

- Es difícil acceder solo a lo que se está tecleando en el momento, por lo que siempre debes recorrer toda la palabra para garantizar que se aplica el estilo tanto al escribir como al borrar, pegar, etc.
- Solo tienes letras de la `a` a la `z` (minúsculas) en el objeto para asignar colores, convierte cada letra a minúscula
- Verifica que la letra existe en el objeto o agrégala sin aplicar estilo (ñ, acentos, espacios, etc.)
- Al final, asignas el resultado como HTML del elemento

Agregué comentarios en el código para que sepas qué es lo que se hace en cada paso.

```js
// Obtener campo y asignar evento
let input = document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener('input', muestra_color);

function muestra_color() {
  let letras = {
    a: '#EA1437',
    b: '#D8EA14',
    c: '#4AEA14',
    d: '#2BA97E',
    e: '#0E1EC2',
    f: '#460EC2',
    g: '#A90EC2',
    h: '#C20E3A',
    i: '#EA1437',
    j: '#D8EA14',
    k: '#4AEA14',
    l: '#2BA97E',
    m: '#0E1EC2',
    n: '#460EC2',
    ñ: '#084213',
    o: '#2C0842',
    p: '#66EAD8',
    q: '#F0E630',
    r: '#6A61A2',
    s: '#A28261',
    t: '#DE2D08',
    u: '#B24C5C',
    v: '#95A5A6',
    w: '#0B5345',
    x: '#34495E',
    y: '#07E816',
    z: '#07E8A0'
  };
  // Tomar valor del campo
  let palabra = input.value;
  // Inicializar HTML de resultado
  let result = '';
  // Recorrer todo el valor del campo, letra por letra
  for(let i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
      // Letra actual
      let letra = palabra[i];
      // Verificar si la letra existe en el objeto (solo hay minúsculas)
      let indice = letra.toLowerCase();
      if(letras.hasOwnProperty(indice)) {
          // Si existe, obtener color y agregar con estilo
          color = letras[indice];
          result += `<span style="color:${color}">${letra}</span>`;
      } else {
          // Si no existe, solo agregar la letra (acentos, espacios, etc.)
          result += letra;
      }
  }
  // Asignar el HTML al elemento
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<div class="wraper-2">
  <input placeholder="Escribe tu nombre" class="txt-resultado" id="input" value="">
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="wraper-3" id="oninput">
  <p class="txt_resultado" id="resultado"></p>
</div>
```

Como nota adicional, y aunque podría ser cuestión de preferencias, considero que es mejor no poner el evento directamente en la etiqueta del campo, sino asignarlo por medio de Javascript, de esta forma, tendrás separado HTML de la lógica y siempre sabrás donde modificar cada uno.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu colaboracion me has ayudado mucho